# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("favorites")

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, favorites

On each user auth and user creation, I have an error message where the method is called on null.

The user is created when I sign up but it prevents me to continue the use without having to restart the apps.

I placed all the call related to user creation in firebase, I can not find the root cause of the null.

[image]

```
class AuthNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseUser _user;
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  void setUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    _user = user;
    _createUserDocument();
    if (user != null) {
      _createUserDocument();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _createUserDocument() async {
    CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection('Users');
    DocumentSnapshot user_document = await users.document(_user.uid).get();
    if (!user_document.exists) {
      // Create a document for the user if he doesn't have one
      users.document(_user.uid).setData({
        'favorites': []
      }
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> toggleFavorite(String foodId) async {
    CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection('Users');
    DocumentSnapshot user_document = await users.document(_user.uid).get();

    // If using collectionGroup, we can directly filter the foodId without looping through it.
    // Fetch and see if it is already in the list // TODO: Use class-wide, static, event-updated instance
    for (dynamic reference in user_document.data['favorites']) {
      if (reference.documentID == foodId) {
        // Remove it from the list and exit so it doesn't get added later in the function
        users.document(_user.uid).updateData({'favorites': FieldValue.arrayRemove([reference])}).catchError((error) => print("Failed to remove favorite element: ${error}"));
        notifyListeners();
        return;
      }
    }

    // Get the matching food DocumentReference object
    var food = await Firestore.instance.collection('Foods').document(foodId).get();
    // Add to the favorite list if it wasn't
    users.document(_user.uid).updateData({'favorites': FieldValue.arrayUnion([food.reference])}).catchError((error) => print("Failed to add new favorite element : ${error}"));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> isFavorite(String foodId) async {
    List<dynamic> favorites = await _getFavorites();
    for (DocumentReference favorite in favorites) {
      if (favorite.documentID == foodId) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getFavorites() async {
    List<dynamic> favorites = await _getFavorites();
    List<String> favorites_documentid = [];
    favorites.forEach((reference) { favorites_documentid.add(reference.documentID); });
    return favorites_documentid;
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _getFavorites() async {  // TODO: Use class-wide list that updates only when a a favorite is added or removed. Even listen to a snapshot for this, if there are lots of favorites.
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Users').document(_user.uid).get();
    return snapshot.data['favorites'];  // DocumentReference
  }

}
```

Comment: this means `snapshot.data` is null

Comment: thanks, how do I integrate it into a new user without having yet the favorite list created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` for async operations to complete.

```
  Future<void> setUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    _user = user;
    await _createUserDocument();
    if (user != null) {
      await _createUserDocument();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> _createUserDocument() async {
    CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection('Users');
    DocumentSnapshot user_document = await users.document(_user.uid).get();
    if (!user_document.exists) {
      // Create a document for the user if he doesn't have one
      await users.document(_user.uid).setData({
        'favorites': []
      }
      );
    }
  }
```

And `await` for `setUser()` as well.

Update. Use `snapshot.data()` instead of `snaphot.data`:

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> _getFavorites() async { 
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Users').document(_user.uid).get();
    return snapshot.data()['favorites'];  // DocumentReference
  }
```

Comment: the error message is still, favorites remains null... Shall I place a return or if on favorites != null ?

Comment: It looks like the doc exists, but does not contain `favorites` field because of previous wrong attempts. Go to Firestore console, remove the document with that `id` and try again.

Comment: the login with no Favorite is working but not the sign up where favorites are not existent yet fails. I see an issue with sequence document creation.

Comment: Use snapshot.data() instead of snaphot.data:DocumentSnapshot snapshot
The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked